# Displaying list values with each button click

Tags: java, android, list

How can i display list items on each button click. Lets say there are 4 names in the list. When I press next it displays the first name. Then when you press next it displays the second name and so on.

The only way I think is using the list.get() method. however I dont know how to use the method so that it knows how many values there are in the list and displaying then on each button hit. I think i need to use for method however I hadnt had any luck with it.

```
public class ZaidimasActivity extends ZaidejaiActivity {

    public TextView mPlayer;
    public TextView mKlausimas;
    public Button mNext;
    public Button mBack;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaidimas);
         /** //get the player list from ZaidejaiActivity
        Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
        String myVal = recdData.getString("playerList"); */

        Intent zaidejuInfo = getIntent();
        Bundle extrasBundle = zaidejuInfo.getExtras();
        final ArrayList<String> players = extrasBundle.getStringArrayList("playerList");

        //show the first players name

        mPlayer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ZaidejoVardas);
        players.size();

        mPlayer.setText(players.get(0));




        mNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.KitasBtn);
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mPlayer.setText(players.get(1));


            }
        });


        mBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GryztiMeniuBtn);
        mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gryztiMeniu = new Intent(ZaidimasActivity.this, ZaidejaiActivity.class);
                startActivity(gryztiMeniu);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, maintain a variable for storing the global array index and increment it every time the button is clicked.

```
private int count = 0; // Global array index. Make it as class field   

final ArrayList<String> players = extrasBundle.getStringArrayList("playerList");



mPlayer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ZaidejoVardas);
players.size();

mPlayer.setText(players.get(0));




mNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.KitasBtn);
mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count++;
        mPlayer.setText(players.get((count)%players.size())); //Incrementing global count and making sure it never exceeds the players list size


    }
});
```